# Hibernate org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException

Tags: hibernate, jsp

I am using hibernate with jsp-servlet. When I am trying to access child element attribute I am getting following exception:

```
 Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.ecomm.ultimatesms.messaging.persistence.pojos.Mno.startnumbers, no session or session was closed
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:380) [:3.3.2.GA]
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:372) [:3.3.2.GA]
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:365) [:3.3.2.GA]
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:108) [:3.3.2.GA]
```

Here is my hibernate mapping files. I am using `hibernate-mapping` `default-lazy="false"`

```
<hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false">
<class name="com.ecomm.ultimatesms.messaging.persistence.pojos.Mno" table="mno" schema="public">

    <id name="pkmnoid" type="long">
        <column name="pkmnoid" />
     <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">mno_pkmnoid_seq1</param>
        </generator>
    </id>

    <property name="name" type="string">
        <column name="name" length="45" />
    </property>

    <set name="startnumbers" table="startnumber" inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="delete">
        <key>
            <column name="fkmnoid" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.ecomm.ultimatesms.messaging.persistence.pojos.Startnumber" />
    </set>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to set all your connection as EAGER.

Alternatively, you need to use Open Session In View Pattern.

You can read more about it here:

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView

Answer (score 1):

One nice way to grant that you still have an open session/entity manager open is to have a filter that injects the EntityManager at the begining of the request than closes its after its execution so youll never care about it anymore. Take a look

```
package com.renatogama.infra.filters;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;

@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*")
public class EntityManagerFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        EntityManager em = new JPAUtil().getEntityManager();
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            request.setAttribute("em", em);
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
            throw new ServletException(e);
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have set `lazy=true` you have to initialize the collection before closing the hibernate session. Here is an article that might help you http://community.jboss.org/wiki/LazyInitializationExceptionovercome

Answer (score 0):

Though you set `lazy='true'`, you described that you set it to `false`. So, that causing the issue as session got closed before you accessing the collection(`startnumbers`). Either change your mapping by setting `lazy='false'` (or) use `Hibernate.initialize()` api to load the collection before session close (or) use [`Open-Session-In-View`](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView) pattern.